# Filtering DataTable and not able to handle empty result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am filtering data from `datatable` using `linq`, it is working fine, except when search criteria doesn't match, the resultant table is not handled for emptiness.
Below is my code:

```
var table = dtTokensInfo.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => r.Field<string>("tokenName").Contains(txtTokenName.Text))
                  .CopyToDataTable();
```

I want table to contain values as filtered from dtTokensInfor, but am not able to handle it when search criteria doesn't match

Answer (score 1):

You should detach the call to CopyToDataTable from the result of the Linq expression

```
DataTable table = null;
var temp = dtTokensInfo.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(r => r.Field<string>("tokenName")
              .Contains(txtTokenName.Text));

if(temp != null)
   table = temp.CopyToDataTable();
```

If you look at the [MSDN page about CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) IEnumerable extension you will notice this between the possible exceptions thrown

> ArgumentNullException:  The source IEnumerable(Of T) sequence is
>   Nothing and a new table cannot be created.

Comment: A classic example of why 'chaining' functions can lead to all sorts of annoying problems.